# ASP.Net Core How to set value to input

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm confused about how to place values in a text form.

I created a simple form.

test.cshtml

```
@@Model.Name is @Model.Name

<form method=post>
    Name:<input asp-for="Name" />
    <button asp-page="test">Submit</button>
</form>
```

test.cshtml.cs is

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string Name { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    Name = "value-get";
    return Page();
}

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    Name = "value-post";
    return Page();
}
```

first get result is

```
@Model.Name is value-get
Name:[value-get] [submit]
```

[image]

OK. This is fine. The Name is now "value-get".

I change the text box value = 123.

```
@Model.Name is value-get
Name:[123][submit]
```

[image]

then post it.

@Model.Name is now "value-post". Because I change it at OnPost. But the text field is still 123.

```
@Model.Name is value-post
Name:[123][submit]
```

[image]

I do same thing at OnGet and OnPost. I can set text field by OnGet, but I can't set it by OnPost.I would like to know why this is the case and tell me about the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding data in client side,it will get value from ModelState prior to Model .You can try to add `ModelState.Clear();` into Post method.

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            Name = "value-post";
            return Page();
        }
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this where I need to modify the value of an input in OnPost code, I add a value assignment in the CSHTML:

```
<form method=post>
    Name:<input asp-for="Name" value="@Model.Name" />
    <button asp-page="test">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the case of a textarea, no value attribute exists so a different approach is needed.   One must add code to the OnPost such as:

```
Name = "value-post";
ModelState["Name"].AttemptedValue = Name; //When using textarea
```